# What does xxd -r -p do?

Tags: bash, hashsum, xxd, sha1sum

So I am trying to calculate a SHA1 digest (and base64 encode it) for an attachment I received so it matches their (base64 encoded) digest. Using ChatGPT, I was able to use the command below to succeed. But I don't understand the command `xxd -r -p` or why it's necessary.

`sha1sum foo | awk '{print $1}' | xxd -r -p | base64`

There's two things I don't understand about it:

1. Why is the option `-p` needed? I understand `xxd -r` makes a binary dump of a hexdump, but if I leave off the `-p` it prints nothing while the man page says it should print to stdout and that `-p` is just for a particular output style.
2. What is the purpose of even passing the SHA1 digest through `xxd`? My understanding is `xxd` essentially converts data between hex and binary. But when I run the above command without `xxd -r -p`, it gives a different, and unmatched, output. I do know what hex style/representation is (that's the format of a SHA1 digest), but perhaps I don't know what "binary" means in this context?

Comment: Actually, you only need `openssl` for that: `openssl sha1 -binary foo | openssl base64`

Answer (score 3):

First, look at the input to `xxd -r p` to find out what we're dealing with. Here's an example:

```
echo boo | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}'
6132b58967cf1ebc05062492c17145e5ee9f82a8
```

This line generates the SHA1 hash of the *four* characters, `boo` and its trailing newline.

Now let's investigate the `xxd` command a little. The man page for `xxd` (see `man xxd`) explains that the `xxd -r` command reverses a normal hexdump generated by `xxd`. So we can construct a pipeline like this:

```
echo boo | xxd | xxd -r
boo
```

Now contrast these two outputs:

```
echo boo | xxd
00000000: 626f 6f0a                                boo.

echo boo | xxd -p
626f6f0a
```

To reverse the second output into binary we need not only `-r` but also `-p`:

```
echo boo | xxd -p | xxd -r -p
boo
```

This structure (hex bytes without spaces or other formatting, generated by `xxd -p`) happens to match the output from `sha1sum`, which is why that can be converted to binary using this approach. The resulting binary is then (finally!) passed through `base64`, converting it to Base 64:

```
echo boo | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}' | xxd -r -p | base64
YTK1iWfPHrwFBiSSwXFF5e6fgqg=
```

Comment: Gotcha. Tinkered with it myself and the `-p` makes sense as in this case, it matches the format that `sha1sum1` produces. But I still don't understand why the SHA1 digest is passed through `xxd` anyway? Is it because the output of `sha1sum` is actually in ASCII and not binary? As in the output of `sha1sum` is the same ASCII format as the output of `echo boo`?

Comment: I've no idea why you'd want to do that either. Happy to look at the actual problem (rather than your partial solution from ChatGPT that may or may not be accurate). Ask away - for example "Given _this base64 encoded digest_ and _these instructions_ that came with it, how do I validate my download" - and if you like, link it here

Comment: Sorry this took longer than I wanted. These are the two relevant lines from the Python2 program provided. Everything above it is about preparing the attachment I'm calculating the checksum for.
  sha1Hash = hashlib.sha1(encoded_attachment)
  attachmenthash = base64.encodestring(sha1Hash.digest()).strip()

Comment: Unfortunately python code is of little use to me, @geckels1

Comment: Ah sry. Those are the only "instructions" I've been given. Yes, this web service is frustrating to use. But you have been very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @geckels1 the code you originally supplied is a shell pipeline. But here you're using python. Is that because the shell pipeline was only an approximation to your reality? Normally I'd expect a digest to be verifiable per [How to verify the checksum of a downloaded file (pgp, sha, etc.)](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/189004/77217)

Comment: Correct the python is what the Web Service provider gave me, but the shell pipeline I discovered myself.